# Is this a conditional 'if' in "These results don't conform to Stenseth ... (1992) expectations if dispersal governs patterns of population dynamics."?

Tags: grammar

Is this a conditional '**if**' ? or it connects next information to "Stenseth and Lidicker's expectations" ? or something else?

> These results do not conform to Stenseth and Lidicker's (1992)
> expectations **if** dispersal governs patterns of population dynamics.

Comment: "if" is always conditional. The heat does not work if the electricity fails.

Comment: Thank you @Lambie. What about this example : "Ask David if he knows John." ? Can it mean something like this?

Comment: This is not true (these results do not conform to A and B) if Y (the rest of the sentence) is true. Can't you see that? :) You might want to look up the verb govern.

Comment: I had doubts :) Thank you again for your time dear @Lambie.

Comment: No worries. I will enter it as an answer.

Comment: I would understand that as "If we accept the proposition that 'dispersal governs patterns of population dynamics' then these results do not conform to Stenseth and Lidicker's expectations which were set forth in their 1992 article."  The logic of the sentence is not immediately clear to someone unfamiliar with the topic.  It seems to suggest that the results contradict Stenseth and Lidicker.

Comment: Thank you @TimR on some device.
 I think you are right about the "contradict" and It seems that "the results" are the same as "dispersal governs patterns of population dynamics".

Comment: These results do not conform to A and B, if x is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"if" is always conditional. The heat does not work if the electricity fails. – Notice the two verbs in the present tense.